# SQL return nothing if it not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I have the following query:

```
select
   max(case when measure_name = 'consumption' then measure_value::double end) 
consumption, 
   max(case when measure_name = 'generation' then measure_value::double end) 
generation,
   max(case when measure_name = 'self_coverage' then measure_value::double end) 
self_coverage, 
   time, 
   point_delivery_number 
from "test_database"."raw" 
GROUP BY time, point_delivery_number 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

This query works ONLY if its not empty. As soon as its empty it says:

> Column 'measure_value::double' does not exist

Is there a way to say like, if there is nothing inside the table just return 0 rows?

Comment: tell us which dbms you are using

Comment: @luisvenezian I am using AWS Timestream DB

Comment: Does AWS Timestream DB really support `::` as cast operand? I'd try `cast(measure_value as double)`.

Comment: @jarlh i am not sure, you can view it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/conversion-functions.html

Comment: I'd expect a semantic error, like column does not exists, to be data independent.

Comment: @jarlh well `measure_value::double` is actually the column name inside `raw` table. Thats how AWS Timestream saves it

Comment: Well, the link you posted doesn't have anything about `::` for a cast. Just try proper cast syntax.

Comment: @Andrew i guess here is some confusion because `measure_value::double` is actually the column name inside `raw` table.

Comment: That's a really messed up column name... Try qualifying it with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use coalesce to convert null to a default value

```
select
   max(case when measure_name = 'consumption' then COALESCE(measure_value::double,0.0) end) 
consumption, 
   max(case when measure_name = 'generation' then COALESCE(measure_value::double,0.0) end) 
generation,
   max(case when measure_name = 'self_coverage' then COALESCE(measure_value::double,0.0) end) 
self_coverage, 
   time, 
   point_delivery_number 
from "test_database"."raw" 
GROUP BY time, point_delivery_number 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: Well i still got the error. I am using AWS Timestream DB if it helps. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/what-is-timestream.html

Comment: @bill.gates -- does the column exist?  The SQL I posted is valid SQL for over 30 years

Comment: it does not. Only after i insert data into it

Comment: I don't understand.  If the column does not exist you can't query it.

Comment: I'd expect the `::` cast to return null for null values.

Comment: Try this:  `COALESCE(measure_value,0.0)::double`

Comment: also try adding else

Comment: @Hogan well `::` seems to be not supported i get syntax error. Here are the casts that are supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/conversion-functions.html

Comment: coalesce is not a cast it is a base part of every SQL ever made.  Of course this SQL supports it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/conditional-expressions.COALESCE.html

Comment: @Hogan `measure_value::double` is actually the column name inside of `raw` table.